# Does $\text{Tor}_1^R(M, M) = M$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, tensor-products, solution-verification, derived-functors

Let $k$ be a field and let $R = k[x]$. Consider the $R$-module $M := \frac{k[x, x^{-1}]}{x \cdot k[x]}$ (i.e. so typical elements are Laurent polynomials with no positive powers).

I have computed $\text{Tor}_1^R(M, M) = M$ (see below); is this correct? Is the proof below correct?

---

Let $L$ denote the $R$-module $k[x, x^{-1}]$. Then we have a short exact sequence

$$0 \longrightarrow R \xrightarrow{1\, \mapsto \,x} L \longrightarrow M \longrightarrow 0$$

This induces the long exact sequence

$$
\begin{alignat}{3}
\cdots & \longrightarrow \text{Tor}_1^R (M, L) && \longrightarrow \text{Tor}_1^M(M, M) & & \longrightarrow \\
M \otimes_R R & \longrightarrow M \otimes_R L && \longrightarrow  M \otimes_R M  & & \longrightarrow 0\\
\end{alignat}
$$

Since $L$ is flat, $\text{Tor}_1^R (M, L) = 0$.

Also, consider an element $(x^{-n} \otimes_R x^{-m}) \in M \otimes_R M$. We have

$$
x^{-n} \otimes x^{-m} = x^{-n} \otimes (x^{n+1} \cdot x^{-n - m - 1}) = (x^{n+1} \cdot x^{-n}) \otimes x^{-n -m -1} = 0
$$

so that $M \otimes_R M = 0$. Similarly, $M \otimes_R L = 0$.

Hence, the long exact sequence reduces to

$$0 \longrightarrow \text{Tor}_1^R(M, M) \longrightarrow M \longrightarrow 0$$

That is, $\text{Tor}_1^R(M, M) \simeq M$.

Comment: Your proof seems good to me.

Comment: @CaptainLama Thanks for the verification!